# Should I register a per request concrete class using a lambda with Autofac?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am new to Autofac and am researching different best practices.  Per this [Best Practices and Recommendations](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/best-practices/#register-frequently-used-components-with-lambdas) document, it is recommended that frequently used components should be registered using lambdas.

I have a concrete class, `CurrentUser` that implements `IUserIdentity`.  This concrete class takes in `HttpContextBase` in order to retrieve the user's identity (id, roles, etc).  My services obviously depend upon `IUserIdentity`.

I am *currently* registering this like this:

`builder.RegisterType<CurrentUser>().As<IUserIdentity>().InstancePerRequest()`

After reading this article, I am wondering if I should register it using a lambda since this will get resolved *many* times?

If so, how do I provide `HttpContextBase` since in my current code Autofac resolves it for me.

Comment: Your link also says: "[this] only makes sense for components that appear in many object graphs."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should worry about this unless you are actually optimizing your code, but in the event that you do still want to do it it would look something like this:

```
builder.Register(context => {
    var contextBase = context.Resolve<HttpContextBase>();
    return new CurrentUser(contextBase);
}).As<IUserIdentity>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: I must say I am uncomfortable with writing "un-optimized" code ;)  Thank you for the tip on how to do the lambda!